# c# MVC5 Referencing Table if value is not null

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

Is there a way to reference a primary key only if the value I am entering is not null.  For example, a Foreign key cannot be null, but I wish to have a foreign key restraint on a field when a value is entered, and allow null.

```
public class Team
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public bool AllowComments { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Member")]
        public int Captain { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Member")]
        public int? CoCaptain { get; set; }

        public virtual Member Member { get; set; }
    }
```

With the above setup, I can only create a record if I enter a CoCaptain, however I wish CoCaptain to be optional and when entered then it references Member.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly and you need this table:

```
 - Id (PK, int, not null) 
 - AllowComments (bit, not null)
 - Captain (FK, int, not null)
 - CoCaption (FK, int, null)
```

Because you have 2 foreign-key properties, you need to have 2 navigation properties too.

So, create 2 navigation properties and correct foreign key attributes, then you can use using `int` for `Caption` to make it `not null` and using `int?` for `CoCaption` makes it allows `null` and

```
public class Team
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public bool AllowComments { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Member")]
    public int Captain { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CoMember")]
    public int? CoCaptain { get; set; }

    public virtual Member Member { get; set; }

    public virtual Member CoMember { get; set; }
}
```

If you only need one foreign-key column, you should have only one navigation property too. And using `int?` for foreign-key property, makes it allow `null` in database.

For more information:

- [Code First Conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj679962.aspx)
- [Code First DataAnnotations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg193958.aspx)